# collection_size_error: TOO_MANY

Tags: google-ads-api

[image]I am trying to add users to the newly created audience in Google ads API but I am getting the following response from the API. I want to understand what is possibly causing this error and how to fix this?

```
Set<String> userList;  //this contains Hashed data(email of user that I want to upload)

  List<UserDataOperation> userDataOperations = new ArrayList<>(userList.size());

   for (String user : userList) {
    UserDataOperation userDataOperationEmail = UserDataOperation.newBuilder().setCreate(
        UserData.newBuilder()
            .addUserIdentifiers(UserIdentifier.newBuilder().setHashedEmail(user).build())
            .build()).build();
    userDataOperations.add(userDataOperationEmail);
   }
```

Comment: You can find the definition of this error [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v10/CollectionSizeErrorEnum.CollectionSizeError?hl=en). I'd say that the issue is that you're adding too many members to a list at the same time in your request, but you'd have to add additional details to your question in order to get a definite answer.

Comment: I'm having a TOO_FEW error when creating a new responsive ad and there's no indication of what it is I have too few of. @dorian any suggestion on how to debug such errors? Is there some kind of rule of thumb?

Comment: @AdamGenshaft It's possible that you don't provide the minimum number of assets. You'll need at least [3 headlines and 2 descriptions](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7684791).

Comment: @dorian this is the exact response that I am getting. I also think I am adding too many members to the list at the same time. If I want to add too many members at the same time what's the best way to do it?

Body: null
Failure message: errors {
  error_code {
    collection_size_error: TOO_MANY
  }
  message: "Too many."
  location {
    field_path_elements {
      field_name: "operations"
    }
  }
}
request_id: 

Status: Status{code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, description=Request contains an invalid argument., cause=null}.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion in the comments, it seems that a likely cause for the error is that you're trying to add more than [100'000 users](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/remarketing/audience-types/customer-match#customer_match_considerations) to a user list at a time in your [`AddOfflineUserDataJobOperationsRequest`](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v11/AddOfflineUserDataJobOperationsRequest).

Try splitting up your user IDs into multiple requests with the same job resource name.

Comment: I am using the code given in the image above to add a user to the audience(userLst that I created in google ads API). But I see that when I add more than 10 users(when the userList set size is greater than 10) when making calls to google ads I get this Collection size error. Please check the code snippet updated in ques

Comment: Please provide code snippets as text, not as an image.

Comment: Please find the code snippet below

Set<String> userList;  //this contains Hashed data(email of user that I want to upload)
  List<UserDataOperation> userDataOperations = new ArrayList<>(userList.size());
   for (String user : userList) {
    UserDataOperation userDataOperationEmail = UserDataOperation.newBuilder().setCreate(
        UserData.newBuilder()
            .addUserIdentifiers(UserIdentifier.newBuilder().setHashedEmail(user).build())
            .build()).build();
    userDataOperations.add(userDataOperationEmail);
   }

Comment: Please take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks
As it stands, your code is very hard to read.

Comment: formatted the code @dorian